# PyQGIS: feature added signal throws an error message

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

For my PyQGIS plugin 2.2, I try to:

---

```
def logFeatureAdded(self,layerId,addfeatures): 
    message = str(layerId) + " has features added: " 
    for feature in addedFeatures: 
        message += str( feature.id() ) + ", " 
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage(message) 
    QApplication.beep() 

    layer.featureAdded.connect(self.logFeatureAdded)
```

---

When I try to add a feature, this following error message appears:

> TypeError : logFeaturesAdded() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given).

How can I use the `featureAdded` signal properly?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [QGIS API docs](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ac914dd316a4bb50eb432515950583806), the `featureAdded` signal only passes one argument, namely, the feature ID.

When you create your slot, you must use a single argument (besides `self`), this way:

```py
def logFeatureAdded(self, fid): 
    message = str( fid )
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage(message) 
    QApplication.beep()
```

This should solve your problem!